# Joining two SELECT Statements with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, join, statements

I think this is probably really easy but im not practiced in SQL and dont know much of the syntax.

Basically I got a big table with different `User Complaints` (represented by a `problem ID`) and `Timestamps` that I want to graph.

The individual statements are really easy and straightforward. Example:

```
SELECT DATE( datetimebegin ) AS Date, COUNT( * ) AS CntProb1
FROM `problems` 
WHERE problemID = "1"
GROUP BY Date, problemID;

SELECT DATE( datetimebegin ) AS Date, COUNT( * ) AS CntProb2
FROM `problems` 
WHERE problemID = "2"
GROUP BY Date, problemID;
```

Each Table gives me a pretty simple output:

```
Date, CntProb1
2013-03-11,4
2013-03-14,1
2013-03-17,7

Date, CntProb2
2013-03-12,2
2013-03-13,1
2013-03-14,3
2013-03-17,1
```

I need the result combined like this:

```
Date, CntProb1, CntProb2
2013-03-11,4,0
2013-03-12,0,2
2013-03-13,0,1
2013-03-14,1,3
2013-03-17,7,1
```

I guess this is something really simple if you know the right SQL Syntax... Some kind of Join?!

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a JOIN to get the result, you should be able to get it by using a CASE expression inside of your aggregate function:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(datetimebegin) AS Date, 
    sum(case when problemID = '1' then 1 else 0 end) AS CntProb1,
    sum(case when problemID = '2' then 1 else 0 end) AS CntProb2
FROM `problems` 
WHERE problemID in ('1', '2')
GROUP BY DATE(datetimebegin);
```

If you want to use `count()` instead of `sum()` then you would use:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(datetimebegin) AS Date, 
    count(case when problemID = '1' then problemID end) AS CntProb1,
    count(case when problemID = '2' then problemID end) AS CntProb2
FROM `problems` 
WHERE problemID in ('1', '2')
GROUP BY DATE(datetimebegin);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13025/1) of both queries.

Comment: Your answer looks pretty good and straight forward, however phpMyAdmin returns the following error: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `problems` WHERE problem in ('1', '2')' at line 5"

Comment: @PetervonFrostata  I'm not sure why you are getting an error - the syntax works - see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13025/1  -- Your comment is using `problem in` but you stated above it was `problemId` what is the correct name?

Comment: My bad, you just added a comma too much in front of "FROM". However your Statement does not list up individual dates it just gives me the first date with a cumulative sum of all problems

Comment: @PetervonFrostata The two queries in my answer use a GROUP BY and it will return a list of each date in your table.

Comment: yes sorry I changed the names a bit for the question to make it a bit more generic. At this stage I am just playing around and dont want to raise to much discussion about do's and dont's ;) Without the comma in front oft the "FROM" your Statement works however it returns just one line: "2013-03-20, 21,8" instead of multiple lines with multiple dates.

Comment: @PetervonFrostata Are you using the full code that I posted including the GROUP BY?

Comment: Again sorry :) i think you edited your answer after originally posting it. I just saw your statement without a GROUP BY until i just hit refresh. With the GROUP BY it works exactly as I need it! Thank you very much for your time and help :)